# CoffeeScript - How to work with coffeescript in ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am working with CoffeeScript in Ruby on rails. And I am using http://js2.coffee/ to convert my javascript and jquery into CoffeeScript.

We know, Ruby on Rails provides us by default .coffee files when we create any controller.

In my view folder, I have defined a `test.html.erb` file, I have a button

```
<button id="p">try</button>
```

and if I define the script for this button by using javascript or jquery in the same page i.e. `test.html.erb` it works.

My javascript code

```
document.getElementById("p").onclick = function() {myFunction()};
function myFunction() {
    alert("hello");
}
```

and my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#p").click(function(){
        alert("hello");
    });
});
```

And now I have created a custom file in `app/assets/javascripts/test.coffee`

coffeescript of my jquery code

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#p').click ->
    alert 'hello'
    return
  return
```

and when I use this in my test.coffee it works fine.

coffeescript of javascript code

```
myFunction = ->
  alert 'hello'
  return

document.getElementById('p').onclick = ->
  myFunction()
  return
```

and when I use this code in my test.coffee it shows error in my console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
```

I have also try the `test.js.coffee` but still get the same error

so should I only use the coffeescript generated by jquery or is there any way to use the coffeescript generated by javascript?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is element_with_id "p" is not found on the page because coffeescript is being load before the page load. Wrap your code inside `document.ready` this will call the coffeescript once the page is completed loaded.

```
$(document).ready ->
  myFunction = ->
   alert 'hello'
   return

  document.getElementById('p').onclick = ->
    myFunction()
    return
```

Comment: Thanks, that was my mistake, I did not know that

Answer (score 1):

Your first method is called after document ready, but your last one is called earlier than the first one in which time the element with id of 'p' may haven't created yet, so `document.getElementById('p')` return null, and raise the error above.

Comment: Thanks, that was my mistake, I did not know that

Answer (score 0):

We can add java-script using back-tick(`) in coffee-scripts.

```
window.onload = ->
   `document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

   function myFunction() {
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
   }`
```